# Question on SQL Aggregation - error to show data only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rank

I'm trying to aggregate to show the earliest rejected (case #, created_on, status, and amount) and approved rows within the same case#. When I put a min() function to return the earliest rejected transaction, it returns an error. Can anyone help?

[raw data]

[image: 1]

[expected result]

[image: 2]

Comment: tag your databse

Comment: Please remove the images and add data as text, tag your dbms, the query you are trying and the full error you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select * from ( 
   select * , rank() over (partition by case_num, status order by created_on) as rn 
   from tablename
) t where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. However the ranking includes the approved rows as well. When I added the where clause (where status = "rejected") within the ranking partition the final output excludes the approved rows. 

Technically, the ranking should only work within the rejected rows.....

Any other guidance?

Comment: @encamped this is producing what you showed as desired output , you don't need to add anything to this query

Comment: I think the query will rank the rows regardless of the status for the same case_num the it will capture only the lowest value (where rn=1). Therefore the approved rows are missed.